# SpringBatch - With Mysql Filesort Performance

Tags: mysql, spring-batch

I am not sure if this is a mysql question or spring batch

I am using spring batch to read data from mysql database (Using JdbcPagingItemReader)
There are close to 1 million records that I am trying to read with fetch and pageSize of 10000
The issue is that read operation for each batch of 10000 records is very slow. I analysed the sql with explain and it is because even though there is index and all, due to sort by primary key, mysql uses internally filesort.

Has anyone faced similar issue before?

Sorry if the details are not sufficient (I havent provided the query, but its simple query with couple of joins and group by. All the join ids are indexed and sorting is based on primary key)

Comment: Have you tried to run query with a sql client outside of your Spring Batch job? Do you have the same performance issue? This should allow you to isolate the problem (at least answer your first question `I am not sure if this is a mysql question or spring batch`).

Comment: yes as mentioned above when doing explain (using the query that spring batch generates), I see that with many records and order by the query uses file sort. So the question was if someone hit similar issue with performance with such big data set and mysql resulting in filesort and ignoring index since spring batch expect order by clause which causes this

Comment: "simple query with couple of joins and group by" -- that _may_ be more complex than you realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT 10000
```

Must do the grouping and sorting *before* imposing the LIMIT.

In some cases the query can be "turned inside out" to locate the 10000 *first* (in a subquery), *then* do JOINs, etc  This *may* run faster.

We need to study the actual query, not talk in generalizations.  Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there may be a missing composite index and/or some datatype issues.  Please provide the generated SQL, not Spring's rendition of it.